# Custom postgres shared_preload_libraries dir - how to configure?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) extension in postgres in alpine linux docker.
When running

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;
```

in psql console I get:
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/pg_cron.control": No such file or directory

The problem is that the actual pg_cron.control is not under /usr/local/share/... but under /usr/share/..
Where in postgresql.conf I can define the path?

Steps taken:

```
docker run --name postgres-0 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Password1 -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:10-alpine

docker exec -it postgres-0 /bin/bash
apk update
apk add postgresql-pg_cron --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community

cat <<EOT >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
shared_preload_libraries='pg_cron'
EOT

pg_ctl reload
```

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL expects to find the extension files in the `SHAREDIR/extension/` directory associated with the installation (execute `pg_config --sharedir` to confirm the value of `SHAREDIR` for your particular installation).

There is however no facility for specifying an alternative location for extension files; it looks like something is wrong with the packaging.

I'm not familiar with Alpine Linux, but a quick Google search brings up e.g. this issue: [Postgres extensions are installed into incorrect path](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/7772) and the suggested solution is to use a bare Alpine Linux image and install PostgreSQL via the `apk` command, so you might want to try that.